# Change language and double property in a jQuery Validation Plugin

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate

1. I need change a language of communiques.

I changed name of communique in jquery.validate.js

```
messages: {
        required: "This field is required.",
        remote: "Please fix this field.",
        ............
        min: $.validator.format("Please enter a value greater than or equal to {0}.")
    },
```

But I have communique:
The field name is required.

1. I need change a double property, because project/form/database accept **1,1** but Validation script show error and accept only **1.1**

Does any body now where I can change it?